# What does "should be borne in mind" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

When searching borne online, its meaning says past of bear. When reading a paper, it states: "These findings should be borne in mind by designers". Contextually it sounds like designers should keep it in mind, but is there a different meaning or emphasis that this phrasing creates?

Comment: Not really. As a BrE speaker, *keep in mind that...* sounds odd to me when something is being mentioned for the first time, whereas *bear in mind that...* is fine - but I can't think of any good reason for this and I have only noticed it because AmE speakers use *keep in mind that...* that way all the time.

Comment: There's a subliminal difference between subjunctive as a mode of future, and imperative as a mode of presence. I guess that's the difference, @Minty? Otherwise be reminded that "to keep animals" means basically "to hold".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The past participle implies that the action, a learning process, should be completed, which implies that the idea shall become innert knowledge, whereas *bear in mind* rather sounds like the *burden* of permanently avoiding to forget the idea.

The difference is minicule, if the later is the path to the former. As far as I understand, it simply means "know that ..." or even "appreciate" (in the sense that *value appreciates*, "may grow and improve"; Cp *Ger *Bürde; Würde* "honour, responsibility; dignity").

The difference to *keep in mind* is regional, as @minty points out in the comments.

Comment: PS: I had speculated elsewhere that *keep* "to look for, guard" had come under the influence of a reflex of PIE \*kept "to take", whence *to capture, to have*, but I could not say when or where and the idea was rejected by the community (over at Ger.SE about *aufheben* "to keep, store; to pick up", but also quite counterintuitively "to abolish, deprecate, to lift [a ban]" etc, which had borne the question).

Comment: Also compare, or rather, do not confuse: *to bear [a child]* "to carry, produce" (cp. *birth*); *bear* "naked" (from *to obviate, show*?), and perhaps Ger *verbergen* "to hide" (as to keep hidden).

Comment: it is the past vs present that was what seemed unique to me, the keep vs bear was just my own rephrasing for explanation